# Cannot load libcuda.so.1

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Shotcut fails to export to anything but webm and AVI with error:

```
[h264_nvenc @ 0x7f9c7c001f40] [Eval @ 0x7f9c90b19f60] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'wpred'
[h264_nvenc @ 0x7f9c7c001f40] Unable to parse option value "wpred-dct8x8"
[aac @ 0x7f9c7c01ee40] [Eval @ 0x7f9c90b19ef0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'wpred'
[aac @ 0x7f9c7c01ee40] Unable to parse option value "wpred-dct8x8"
[h264_nvenc @ 0x7f9c7c001f40] Cannot load libcuda.so.1
```

I am on Ubuntu 21.04, [GeFOrce] GTX 1050, NVIDIA 510. This did not help:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `dpkg -S libcuda.so.1` to find out which package(s) provide `libcuda.so.1`. Install that (one of those) package.

Comment: It seems the latest is already installed
 


`$ dpkg -S libcuda.so.1
libnvidia-compute-510:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
libnvidia-compute-510:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1`

`$ ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 May 13 12:05 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.510.73.05`